# Mostrar botones dependiendo del valor de X, Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia, Tengo una incógnita. Es posible crear botones dependiendo los saltos de linea que se dean?.

Prácticamente trato de crear esto. Hago web scraping y me extrae una lista de nombres con `for`. Luego extraigo los enlaces hacia esos nombres. Quiero crear un botones para cada nombre que se extraiga y cada botón abrirá una ventana nueva y mostrare ahí el web scraping que haga con su enlace del nombre, Como es la misma cantidad que los nombres, No tendré problema es que si haya mas o menos cantidad de nombres o enlaces, Siempre estarán parejos.

Entonces si presiono el primer botón que debería tener el enlace del primer nombre, Lo usare para hacerle otro web scraping. y los datos de ese web scraping lo usare para mostrarlo en una ventana emergente con un `def createNewWindow(): newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)` Dejo un ejemplo.

Primer nombre ->   Primer Boton

Segundo nombre --> Segundo Boton

Tercer nombre ---> Tercer boton

Este es mi codigo con el que extraigo los nombres.

```
   for listt in soup1.find_all('h3',class_="Title"):
      string += listt.getText()+"\n"
```

y con esto extraigo los enlaces.

```
   for lin in soup1.find_all('a',class_="link-anime"):
      stringg += lin.get('href').rsplit("/",1)[1]+"\n"
```

y con esto creo un boton que me habra una ventana

```
def createNewWindow():
    newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
buttonExample = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Create new window",command=createNewWindow)
buttonExample.pack()
```

Entonces busco mostrar varios botones dependiendo de cuantos `href` extraiga, Si no es posible lo que menciono, Me gustaria ver otras opciones de como lograr lo que busco. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de almacenar los enlaces en un *string* (`str`) puedes utilizar listas (`list`). Por ejemplo:

```
lista = []
for lin in soup1.find_all('a',class_="link-anime"):
    enlace = lin.get('href').rsplit("/",1)[1]
    lista.append(enlace)
```

Ahora puedes utilizar un bucle que itere sobre los elementos de la lista (sobre los enlaces que has extraido) para crear los botones:

```
for enlace in lista:
    button = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Create new window",command=createNewWindow)
    button.pack()
```

Si los índices de los títulos que has extraido son los mismos que los de los enlaces (es decir, si están en el mismo orden en la página web), un ejemplo completo sería el siguiente:

```
def createNewWindow(ev):
    newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    etiqueta = tkiter.Label(newWindow, text=ev.widget._href)
    etiqueta.pack

lista_titulos = []

for listt in soup1.find_all('h3',class_="Title"):
    titulo = listt.getText()
    lista_titulos.append(titulo)

lista_enlaces = []

for lin in soup1.find_all('a',class_="link-anime"):
    enlace = lin.get('href').rsplit("/",1)[1]
    lista_enlaces.append(enlace)


i = 0
while i < len(lista_titulos):
    titulo = lista_titulos[i]
    enlace = lista_titulos[i]
    button = tkinter.Button(ventana, text=titulo,command=createNewWindow)
    button._href = enlace
    i += 1
```

Este ejemplo presupone que los *títulos* y los *enlaces* están en el mismo índice en sus respectivas listas. Este ejemplo solamente funcionará si `len(lista_titulos) == len(lista_enlaces)`.

Echa un vistazo a [Abrir nueva ventana con click a etiqueta, Tkinter Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/378976/abrir-nueva-ventana-con-click-a-etiqueta-tkinter-python/379268#379268),
tu otra pregunta sobre esto.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por responder!, Tengo un problema. Para poder mostrar todo el texto que devolvia el `for` yo utilizaba `string += listt.getText()+"\n"`, De lo contrario el Label solo msotraria la ultima palabra extraída del `for`

Comment: Si necesitas unir los títulos podrías crear el *string* a partir de la *lista* así: `string="\n".join(lista_titulos)`