# Abrir nueva ventana con click a etiqueta, Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen dia. Mi pregunta es basicamente el titulo. Estoy haciendo web scraping y me da una lista de enlaces. Eso lo muestro como etiquetas en tkinter, Busco que al darle click a esa etiqueta me abra otra ventana y ahi mostrar informacion que extraere a ese enlace clickeado.

Con esto tengo una lista de enlaces.

```
   for lin in soup1.find_all('a',class_="link-anime"):
         stringg += lin.get('href').rsplit("/",1)[1]+"\n"
```

Como uniria un Toplevel a cada etiqueta?

```
newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al crear cualquier *widget* en *Tkinter* puedes utilizar su método `bind` con el argumento `'<Button-1>'` para que al hacer click se ejecute una función (no solo para botones).

Por ejemplo, para una sola etiqueta podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import tkinter


def show_info(ev):
    newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)


ventana = tkinter.Tk()

etiqueta = tkinter.Label(ventana, text='Ejemplo')

etiqueta.pack()

etiqueta.bind('<Button-1>', show_info)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Para asociar información sobre un enlace a un `Label` puedes utilizar, por ejemplo, un diccionario (`dict`) cuyas **claves** sean las *etiquetas Label* y los **valores** sean *objetos que almacenan la información del enlace*.

No obstante, al ser *python* un lenguaje en el que puedes asignar nuevos atributos a objetos dinámicamente, en el ejemplo anterior podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import tkinter


def show_info(ev):
    newWindow = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    info = tkinter.Label(newWindow, text=ev.widget._href) # <-- Atención
    info.pack()

ventana = tkinter.Tk()

etiqueta = tkinter.Label(ventana, text='Ejemplo')

# print(etiqueta._href) <-- Error, no existe el atributo _href
etiqueta._href = 'https://google.es' # <-- Creamos el atributo _href en la asignación

etiqueta.pack()

etiqueta.bind('<Button-1>', show_info)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Aquí debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Dentro de la función `show_info` te refieres al *widget* que disparó el *evento click* mediante `ev.widget` (la etiqueta que ha sido *clickeada*).
- `etiqueta._href` es un atributo que me he inventado para almacenar la dirección del enlace. Podrías haber utilizado cualquier identificador en lugar de `_href`. Debes tener cuidado de no sobrescribir accidentalmente atributos del *widget* que ya existían.